# How can I change the label separator from endash to emdash?

Tags: floats, captions

For some reason I can't redefine the caption from "endash" to "emdash". Gives this kind of error `Package caption Error: Undefined labelseparator` emdash'. \begin{figure}[H]`

I redefine it with this command

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}\captionsetup[figure]{name={Figure},labelsep=endash}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{image.jpeg}\caption{text}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On its own the `caption` package only knows a handful of separators:

- `none`
- `colon`
- `period`
- `space`
- `quad`
- `newline`
- `endash`

(yes, my hand has 7 fingers!). You can define your own labelseps using `\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator`.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{emdash}{\textemdash}
\captionsetup[figure]{name={Figure},labelsep=emdash}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}\caption{text}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```